# QGIS: concats wrong values

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, concatenation

I need to create an `ID`-field in the attribute table for a survey. Since there is more than one person I wanted to create the field in the form "[initials]_[sequence_number]". I have created three different fields in the attribute table:

- `ID`
- Initials of the person
- Sequence number

The name is set up by a list of predefined Initials:

| Wert | Beschreibung |
| --- | --- |
| AB | AB |
| BC | BC |
| CD | CD |

I created the field for the sequence number with the value:

```
count('AB', group_by:= "Person") + 1
```

(somehow it works for all other values too)

The `ID`-field should be a concat of the person and the numberfield. So far so easy - in theory!

If I set up the `ID`-field with ONLY the value of either the person-field OR the sequence number field everything works absolutely fine with the correct values.

[image]

But as soon as I concat these two fields in all the ways I know

```
(concat(), "Person" + "Number", "Person"||"Number")
```

it takes the wrong values:

[image]

The initials are correct, but it always takes the number 1 or the number from the previously selected initials-value.

Can anyone help me to understand, what I am doing wrong, why this error is occurring and/or what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Your value for number should be `count("Person",group_by:="Person") + 1`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes absolutely, sorry, didn't saw that I formated it wrong.